# How Preprocessor define statements able to evaluate runtime environment for simulator?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
#define IS_4_INCH ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)
```

Above IS_4_INCH is having true when i run the app in 4 inch simulator. Being a preprocessor directive how it determines the runtime environment.

I will move this to class method soon. But thought to understand how that statement worked.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preprocessor basically does a string replace (this might be over simplifying it but for your example its ok).

So every time it sees `IS_4_INCH` it will replace it with `([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)`

So for example

```
if(IS_4_INCH) {
```

would turn into

```
if(([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)) {
```

And then the compiler goes off and compiles the code. The compiler does not know that you wrote `IS_4_INCH`.

Answer (score 1):

A preprocessor define just means "replace this string with this other string before compiling." So that method call and test are inserted directly into the code where-ever "IS_4_INCH" appears. Then the method call and test are executed at run time.

Answer (score 0):

Preprocessor will be replaced with value that you defined in the code during the compilation. It will not store any data in it. Here "IS_4_INCH" will be replaced with "([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)" during compilation.

Answer (score 0):

though it contains **IS** in your #define IS_4_INCH, it's not giving an bool after executing the peace of code in front, 
 what it does is : all the places you have used **IS_4_INCH** simply replaced by `([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)`.

```
([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)
```

returns a BOOL